# VS102 Setup including the Setup file for Postgresql Database and Scripts

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2013, setup-project

I am trying to create a windows installer which will include both the application setup files as well as the setup file for the Postgresql Database(if not present in the installed system) with some ddl scripts which will run post installation.

Request you to please guide me on how should i go ahead with meeting the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

[WiX allows you to create installer bundles](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/). This means you can package PostgreSQL and your application in a single installer and let it install PostgreSQL (and other prerequisites) before your application. Other installer solutions have similar capabilities.